# Toolbar doesn't center the button vertically

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, toolbar

Can anyone explain to me why Xcode doesn't vertically center the button when you programmatically add the button to the toolbar? When I work with the toolbar added using the Storyboard, the button appears centered horizontally and vertically.

Toolbar added via a storyboard(looks perfect):
[image]

Toolbar added via a code:
[image]

My code:

```
self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
let testButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
testButton.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
testButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(test), for: .touchUpInside)
testButton.backgroundColor = .black
testButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
testButton.titleLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
let tb = UIBarButtonItem(customView: testButton)
self.toolbarItems = [tb]
```